# Consistent left margin percentage spacing for a horizontal, stacked timeline

Tags: css, percentage, timeline, spacing

I'm making a timeline that has rows for each date or date range with bars to represent the time spans. I figured I'd get the amount of days between the earliest and latest date, and then calculate the width and left margin or each date bar as a percentage (so x% of the total time would be the width, and the time between the start date and the earliest date divided by the total time would be the left margin percentage).

I also wanted to have a vertical bar that goes on top of all of the other rows showing the current date. What I ended up with doesn't seem to be working, though.

Whenever I change the width of the screen, the "current date" bar doesn't stay in the same relative position as the other bars. The normal date bars appear to be functioning properly, though.

Is there a better/more consistent way of accomplishing this?

Here's a jsfiddle with the full html and css along with the class for the 'current date' line:

https://jsfiddle.net/cLxw5atv/

```
.current-date-bar {
background-color: green; 
height:110%; 
width: 3px; 
margin-left:35%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, but I had to add the current date bar to each of the rows and use a margin offset. I'm not sure if there's a better way of accomplishing this, but if anyone is curious how I got it working, I made an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bnztvkL4/1/

```
<div class="centered-contents" style="margin-top: 50px;">
<div class="timeline">
<div class="timeline-container">

    <div class="timeline-date">
        <div class="timeline-date-label">
        Date 1
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-date-contents">
            <div class="date-bar timeline-tooltip" style="width: 38%; margin-left:0%;">
                <span class="timeline-tooltiptext">03/30/2020 - 04/30/2020</span>
            </div>
            <div class="current-date-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="timeline-date timeline-date-alt">
        <div class="timeline-date-label">
        Date 2
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-date-contents">
            <div class="date-bar timeline-tooltip" style="width: 70%; margin-left:10%;">
                <span class="timeline-tooltiptext">04/12/2020 - 08/19/2020</span>
            </div>
            <div class="current-date-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="timeline-date">
        <div class="timeline-date-label">
        Date 3
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-date-contents">
            <div class="date-bar timeline-tooltip" style="width: 30%; margin-left:60%;">
                <span class="timeline-tooltiptext">06/30/2020 - 09/14/2020</span>
            </div>
            <div class="current-date-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="timeline-date timeline-date-alt last-date">
        <div class="timeline-date-label">
        Date 4
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-date-contents">
            <div class="date-bar timeline-tooltip" style="width: 10px; margin-left:100%;">
                <span class="timeline-tooltiptext">10/18/2020</span>
            </div>
            <div class="current-date-bar">
                <div class="current-date-bottom"></div>
                <div class="current-date-text">
                    <span>04/25/2020</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

```
.centered-contents {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.timeline {
    width: 90%;
    color: #7e7e7e;
}

.timeline-container {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline-date {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.last-date {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.timeline-date-label,
.timeline-date-contents {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}

.timeline-date-contents {
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.timeline-date-label {
    min-width:100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
    text-align: right;
}

.timeline-current-date {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.date-bar {
    background-color: #7BAAF7;
    height:20px;
}

.date-bar:hover {
    background-color: #9bb5de;
}


.current-date-bar {
  background-color: green;
  width: 2px;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top:-30px;
}

.current-date-text {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -35px;
  top: 100%;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.current-date-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width:2px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 7px;
}

.timeline-date-alt {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.timeline-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.timeline-tooltip .timeline-tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.timeline-tooltip .timeline-tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.timeline-tooltip:hover .timeline-tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```